# Parse push open rate not tracking

Tags: android, parse-platform

[image: Parse documentation screenshot]

[image: Open rate always 0%]

I have problem tracking push open rate

can anyone tell me what is the problem ??

Answer (score 0):

Simply extends you `Receiver` that response for 
`<action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />` from `ParsePushBroadcastReceiver`.

Sometimes analytic reports deliver late !